# Can't access device through network

Tags: networking

I'm trying to interface a device with python. 
The device is connected to another machine in the same network (the university network) and I know it's Port number.

I can access the device from the PC where it is plugged with the following code:

```
dev = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
dev.connect(('137.195.53.140',51019))
```

where '137.195.53.140' is the PC ip, and 51019 is the port number.

However, if I try the same from another machine, ipython gets stack at the command "dev.connect(('137.195.53.140',51019))", and when I abort the evaluation and then look at "dev" I get this:

```
<socket.socket fd=15, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('137.195.204.85', 50393)>
```

where '137.195.204.85' is the IP of the machine I'm using, and the port number I've no idea.

Since ssh works with no problem within this network, I thought that my approach for accessing the device would have worked as well.

Does anyone have any clue for this? I'm sorry if I haven't been clear, but I know absolutely nothing of networking (and not very much of Python either tbh).

Answer (score 0):

There's couple of things to consider:

- Your university network ports
- Your device's opened ports

Your network might have the `51019` port blocked. Also, ssh uses port 22 to make it's connection. Every port is a world, so there's the chance that just because 22 is open, it doesn't mean that another is. School networks usually have a pretty rigid policy on port closing for security and blocking unwanted sites too.

You can test your device access by pinging it as

`$ ping 137.195.204.85`

If that works, then you can go trying different ports

Comment: Thanks! I did these two tests from the machine NOT connected to the device:
ping 137.195.204.85 (IP of the machine NOT connected to the device)
Output:
PING 137.195.204.85 (137.195.204.85): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 137.195.204.85: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
64 bytes from 137.195.204.85: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
...

ping 137.195.53.140 (IP of the machine plugged to the device)
Output:
PING 137.195.53.140 (137.195.53.140): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1

In any case, is there a criteria for choosing a suitable port?

Comment: Usually, system reserves ports below 2000 (or so). Try to use port numbers over 3000 and you'll be fine. Do a test: on your device, being it a linux, open a term and run `nc -l 3005` and from your pc try to send something to it with `telnet 137.195.53.140 3005` and then write anything there. It should be printed on your device. If not, there's no connection.

Comment: I'll try some ports over 3000 thousand thanks!
Unfortunately, I can't run the test you proposed as the device is not a "computer", but it's a piece of scientific equipment with proprietary software connected to a windows machine, and I'm trying to access the device from a linux machine in the same network of the windows machine (it's kind of complicated to explain :D )